# How to filter stock symbols based on their price momovement in speicifc days using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

[stock price example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMdk2.png)

```
[Id] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
[Symbol] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
[Exchange] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Date] [date] NOT NULL,
[Open] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
[High] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
[Low] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
[Close] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
[Volume] [int] NOT NULL,
[Timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
```

I have stock time series data base stored like above(There also is a screen shot above, please click stock price example), time range is about one year for 8000 symbols.

I am trying to filter the symbol based on their 5 days price drop.

For example:

Choose Symbol A if its closed price has dropped 15% more than Symbol "SPY" (I choose SPY as benchmark here) during the past 5 calendar days(includes weekend)
, if SPY has rised 7% during the past 5 calendar days, then if a symbol has dropped 8% or more on the same period then it is going to be selected. I'd like to apply this crieria for each row (which means for every day every symbol in the data base)

pseudocode is like:

```
if (SPY_2018_03_07 - SPY_2018_03_03)/(SPY_2018_03_03) -

(stock_A_2018_03_07 - stock_A_2018_03_03)/(stock_A_2018_03_03) >= 15%

Then Select stock_A
```

But I'm stuck in how to apply this criteria using SQL query. I'm using SQL Server 2017. Does anyone can help me out? Thank you guys.

Comment: Is the goal to end up with just one symbol returned from all the lines or to check every stock line against one line

Comment: And what do you select if the symbol dropped say 10% over the benchmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have actually 2 problems here.

1. You don't have all the values you need in columns. That means that its going to be painful to calculate what you want for every row. What you can do here is to pivot the 5 day close price value into a column. Your header should be something like this:

   Symbol,Exchange,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Close_D5,Volume

I divided this part in 3 parts for better understanding (I didn't test those querys, they might have some sintax mistakes):

```
SELECT 
    EXCHANGE,SYMBOL,DATE,CLOSE
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EXCHANGE,SYMBOL,DATE ORDER BY EXCHANGE,SYMBOL,DATE ASC) AS ROW_NUM,
  name, recovery_model_desc
  INTO #TEMP
FROM <TABLE>


SELECT 
EXCHANGE,SYMBOL,DATE,
CLOSE,
CLOSE_5 = (SELECT CLOSE FROM #TEMP WHERE ROW_NUM = (t.ROW_NUM - 5))
INTO #TEMP2
FROM <TABLE> t

SELECT CLOSE -CLOSE_5 FROM #TEMP3
```

2. You will need to make this filter in more than one step. I suggest you making a stored procedure to pass the parameters you need and return the result, if you do so, you can tune better your strategy. The query should look something like this:

   ```
    DECLARE @INCREASED_VALUE DECIMAL(10,2)
    SET @INCREASED_VALUE = (SELECT CLOSE-CLOSE_D5/CLOSE_D5 FROM <TABLE> WHERE SYMBOL = 'BASE_SYMBOL')
   ```

Now all you need to do is to filter the table like you want:

```
    IF(@INCREASED_VALUE > 8)
    BEGIN
        SELECT SYMBOL,DATE,EXCHANGE
        FROM <TABLE>
        WHERE @INCREASED_VALUE -CLOSE-CLOSE_D5/CLOSE <= 15
    END
```

This query should give you all the dates and symbols with the criteria you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand part2, For part1, I am curious, can I get the Close_D5 just use sql query? It may invole some conditioning, for example, for Monday, we just need add 5 days to get Close_D5. But for Tuesday, add 5 more days we get Sunday, which we don't have data in database(weekend), so we trace back the nearest trading day ----Friday.  Use that day's close price for our Close_D5.

Comment: Actually you can do a more elegant solution than trying to use conditioning in this case. What you can do is to include another column to you data making a incremental ID over symbol, exchange and date.

With that Incremental ID you can make a subquery selecting the close value of the curent field ID - 5.

Comment: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) you can see the OVER command.Don't forget to order by date or you'll have problems with the values. 
Doing this way you will make sure you are going to sum only the dates you have available, excluding holydays and weekends.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply, do you know how to choose the close price five days before? Since the between is going to calculate everything between today and the preceding five days. I only want (price today - price five days before) Thank you!